# CTE vs. IN clause performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, t-sql

Alright SQL Server Gurus, fire up your analyzers.

- I have a list of titles in application memory (250 or so).
- I have a database table "books" with greater than a million records, one of the columns of the table is "title" and is of type nvarchar.
- the "books" table has another column called "ISBN"
- books.title is not a primary key, is not unique, but is indexed.

So I'd like to know which is more efficient:

```
WITH titles AS (select 'Catcher and the Rye' as Title
                union all 'Harry Potter ...'
                ...
                union all 'The World Is Flat')

select ISBN from books, titles where books.title = titles.title;
```

OR:

```
select ISBN from books where title in ('Catcher and the Rye','Harry Potter',...,'The World Is Flat');
```

OR:

```
???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have ISBN includes on the title index to avoid key lookups

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Titles ON dbo.Books (Title) INCLUDE (ISBN)
```

Now, the IN vs JOIN vs EXISTs is a common question here. The CTE is irrelevant except for readability. Personally, I'd use exists because you'll get duplicates with JOIN for books with the same title, which folk often forget.

```
;WITH titles AS (select 'Catcher and the Rye' as Title
            union all 'Harry Potter ...'
            ...
            union all 'The World Is Flat')
SELECT
    ISBN 
FROM
    books
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * --or null or = all the same
        FROM
            titles 
        WHERE
            titles .Title = books.Title)
```

However, one construct I'd consider is this to force "intermediate materialisation" on my list of search titles. The *also* applies to an exists or CTE solution too. This is likely to help the optimiser considerably.

Edit: a temp table is a better option, really, as Steve mentioned in his comment

```
SELECT
    ISBN 
FROM
    (
    SELECT TOP 2000000000
        Title
    FROM
        (select 'Catcher and the Rye' as Title
                union all 'Harry Potter ...'
                ...
                union all 'The World Is Flat'
        ) foo
    ORDER BY
       Title
    ) bar
    JOIN
    books On bar.Title = books.Title


SELECT
    ISBN 
FROM
    books
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * --or null or = all the same
        FROM
            (
            SELECT TOP 2000000000
                Title
            FROM
                (select 'Catcher and the Rye' as Title
                        union all 'Harry Potter ...'
                        ...
                        union all 'The World Is Flat'
                ) foo
            ORDER BY
               Title
            ) bar
        WHERE
            bar.Title = books.Title)
```

Comment: Trust the optimizer. Only if you find out from real testing that it's not making a wise choice should you even begin to consider trying to coax particular behavior.

In any case, this use of TOP/ORDER BY is a terrible way to do what you can much more readably do by inserting the sought titles into an indexed table variable or temporary table and joining on that.

A future optimizer improvement might well ignore the TOP, in fact, because it has no semantic meaning when the table expression it applies to has fewer than 2000... rows.

Comment: @Steve: Good points, I forgot about temp table/table vars. I'd use a temp table for statistics/cardinality/est. rows: not a table variable. The TOP/ORDER BY is something I don't use anymore (and not sure of performance) but it *does* allow a single SQL call to happen. I'd also hope it'd be tested against other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Given the choice of the two options, avoid IN clauses, as the number of items within the list goes up the query plan will alter and very quickly convert from a potential Seek to a Scan.

The normal tipping point (and I double checked on the adventure works) is that on the 65th item, it changes plan to a scan from a seek.